Proof regarding Pasch's axiom of order in Euclidean geometry
Theorem: If $A$ and $B$ are two different points, then there exists point C such that $\mathbb{B}(A,C,B)$.
$\mathbb{B}(A,B,C)$ is defined as "point $B$ is in between points $A$ and $C$."
To prove the theorem, two axioms are needed:

If $A$ and $B$ are two different points, then there exists $C$ such that $\mathbb{B}(A,B,C)$
(Pasch's axiom) If $A,B,C$ are three non-collinear points and line $p$ doesn't contain the point $A$ and cuts the line $BC$ at a point $P$ such that $\mathbb{B}(B,P,C)$, then at least one of the statements is true:


$p$ cuts line $CA$ at a point $Q$ such that $\mathbb{B}(C,Q,A)$
$p$ cuts line $AB$ at a point $R$ such that $\mathbb{B}(A,R,B)$

Explanation for Pasch's axiom: Fairly easy to visualize, imagine a triangle $ABC$. Line $p$ enters the interior of the triangle at a point $P$ on line $BC$. Then, $p$ has to exit the triangle interior and can't go through point $A$ so it will pass through $Q$ or $R$ located on $CA$ and $AB$ respecitevly.
Proof:
The problem I have with this proof, is that I didn't understand the application of Pasch's theorem.
We begin the proof by introducing point $D$ such that it is non-collinear to the line $AB$. Next, we use axiom $(1.)$ I mentioned above and extend that line $BD$ to some point $E$ (Point $E$ exists such that $\mathbb{B}(B,D,E)$ according to the axiom). Similarly, now we have line $AE$ ($A\neq E$) so applying the same axiom, we'd get point $F$ such that $\mathbb{B}(A,E,F)$. Here we are supposed to apply Pasch's axiom and get the point $C$ on the line $AB$ but I don't see how to conclude that. I know that $FD$ cuts $BE$ at a point $D$ so there is the entrance into the triangle $ABE$.

Line $$ cuts $$ at a point $$, hence it either cuts $AB$ or $AE$. But $FD$ cannot cut $AE$, otherwise $D=E$. Hence it cuts $AB$.
